# How to send Axios response to fs.readFile in Node.Js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, readfile

I want to get an external file via a URL using `axios` and to then send a response to `fs.readFile` in order to process the data.

I don't want to rewrite the code, so this is why I want to do it this way.

I'm using the code

```
    const fileResponse = await axios({
        url: filePath,
        method: 'GET',
        responseType: 'arraybuffer',
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.data
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error)
            return false
        })

fs.readFile(fileBuffer, function(err, data) {})
```

but I'm getting an error that `fileBuffer` should be a string, even though in the `readFile` docs it says I can also send a buffer.

Does anyone know how I can send a response from `axios` to `fs.readFile`?

Comment: Please provide a *real* [mcve]. You've defined a variable named `fileResponse` and then read a variable named `fileBuffer`. Please **test** your MCVE to make sure it replicates your problem.

Comment: `(new ArrayBuffer()) instanceof Buffer === false`

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to accomplish. The first argument of `fs.readFile` is a path or file descriptor... are you trying to read the file on your local system specified by the HTTP response?